# Why doesn't ORDER BY work in this case?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to print some stats so I have the following code:

```
(SELECT 'There are total', COUNT(Name), 'doctors.' FROM OCCUPATIONS
WHERE Occupation = 'Doctor')
UNION
(SELECT 'There are total', COUNT(Name), 'singers.' FROM OCCUPATIONS
WHERE Occupation = 'Singer')
UNION
(SELECT 'There are total', COUNT(Name), 'actors.' FROM OCCUPATIONS
WHERE Occupation = 'Actor')
UNION
(SELECT 'There are total', COUNT(Name), 'professors.' FROM OCCUPATIONS
WHERE Occupation = 'Professor')
ORDER BY COUNT(Occupation);
```

It counts the occurrences of each occupation. I also need to sort these 4 lines corresponding to each profession by the occurrences. My code does not seem to work however:

```
ERROR 1054 (42S22) at line 4: Unknown column 'Occupation' in 'order clause'
```

What is wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to alias `COUNT(Name`) and use that alias in the `ORDER BY`:

```
(SELECT 'There are total', COUNT(Name) OccupationCount, 'doctors.' FROM OCCUPATIONS
WHERE Occupation = 'Doctor')
UNION
(SELECT 'There are total', COUNT(Name), 'singers.' FROM OCCUPATIONS
WHERE Occupation = 'Singer')
UNION
(SELECT 'There are total', COUNT(Name), 'actors.' FROM OCCUPATIONS
WHERE Occupation = 'Actor')
UNION
(SELECT 'There are total', COUNT(Name), 'professors.' FROM OCCUPATIONS
WHERE Occupation = 'Professor')
ORDER BY OccupationCount;
```

However, you don't have to use `UNION` for these. You could easily use `COUNT` and `GROUP BY` with a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT
    'There are total',
    COUNT(Name) OccupationCount,
    CONCAT(LOWER(Occupation), 's')
FROM OCCUPATIONS
WHERE Occupation IN('Doctor', 'Singer', 'Actor', 'Professor')
GROUP BY Occupation
ORDER BY OccupationCount;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using the column number instead of expression:

```
 ORDER BY 2
```

... will sort by the second column.

`Count(Occupations)` is not something that occurs in the `select` list, or is otherwise available. I assume you intended to sort on what is `Count(name)` in each of the sub queries.